# Why "my IP Address.com" is showing that I've 2 IP address?

Tags: ipv4

A device is assigned unique and single IP address then why my device has 2?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Likely this is reacting to the present of a proxy header somewhere between yourself and the server. The proxy would be injecting a header such as X-Forwarded-For which the site you are viewing is then seeing.

This would allow operators of websites to more usefully report issues such as abuse.

Comment: Does http header X-Forwarded-For is sent with outgoing request or with receiving response from the server?

Comment: The header is sent in the request; but you won't see it from the client; it is inserted as it goes through proxies (if the proxy adds it; it doesn't have to). Not that proxies are often transparent, meaning you don't configure the use of such on the client, but rather the network is configured to redirect content via a proxy, such as for caching or other traffic management reasons.

Comment: Client->proxy server->proxy server injecting XFF which has my public IP address->Remote server

Comment: Correct (though the proxy server could be anywhere along the path in theory)